Verify Signature of SOAP response
My requirement is to verify the signature of the SOAP response.
This is my code:
public bool VerifyXmlSignature(string xml)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument() { PreserveWhitespace = true};
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    XmlNode binarySecurityTokenNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//wsse:BinarySecurityToken", GetNamespaceManager(xmlDoc));
    if (binarySecurityTokenNode == null)
        return false;

    byte[] certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(binarySecurityTokenNode.InnerText);
    X509Certificate2 serverCert = new(certBytes);

    var signatureNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
    SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new(xmlDoc);
    signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement?)signatureNode[0]);

    return signedXml.CheckSignature(serverCert, true);
}

CheckSignature method returns false. I have tried various other ways but nothing seems to work.
